# Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I'm executing a query to return the products of a specific sale in Magento database.

It's working fine for a sale that contains only one product, however, I'm having `Subquery returns more than 1 row` when the sale contains more than one product/row.

Query:

```
SELECT  name,
        qty_ordered,
        item_id,
        original_price,
        discount_percent,
        price,
        tax_percent,

        (SELECT mcpev.value
        FROM magento_sales_flat_order_item msfoi,
        magento_catalog_product_entity_varchar mcpev,
        magento_eav_attribute mea
        WHERE order_id = 1
        AND msfoi.product_id = mcpev.entity_id
        AND mcpev.attribute_id = mea.attribute_id
        AND mea.attribute_code = "cip") AS cip, /*Select CIP*/

        (SELECT mcpev.value
        FROM magento_sales_flat_order_item msfoi,
        magento_catalog_product_entity_varchar mcpev,
        magento_eav_attribute mea
        WHERE order_id = 1
        AND msfoi.product_id = mcpev.entity_id
        AND mcpev.attribute_id = mea.attribute_id
        AND mea.attribute_code = "cip7") AS cip7, /*Select CIP7*/

        (SELECT mcpev.value
        FROM magento_sales_flat_order_item msfoi,
        magento_catalog_product_entity_varchar mcpev,
        magento_eav_attribute mea
        WHERE order_id = 1
        AND msfoi.product_id = mcpev.entity_id
        AND mcpev.attribute_id = mea.attribute_id
        AND mea.attribute_code = "gtin_13") AS gtin13 /*Select GTIN13*/

FROM    magento_sales_flat_order_item
WHERE   order_id = 1
```

I do not see why this error occurs, despite that the root select only (without the inner ones) returns 3 rows, and the inner selects returns also 3 rows .

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: One of your sub-queries must be returning > 1 row. Have you ran each in isolation?

Comment: @Molenpad Yes, it returns more than one row, however, the root query returns also the same number of rows.

Comment: @androniennn At the minute it has no idea how to map the subquery rows to the outer query.

Comment: A subquery, when used as part of the `select` list in the way you have demonstrated, cannot return more than 1 row. The error message is explicit in advising this.

Comment: @Molenpad : With order_id equals to 1, I just have one row . I mean that query can return just one row .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My MySQL knowledge is rusty (at best), but subqueries like this can normally be replaced by a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` to achieve the desired result.

Something like this will get you on your way:

```
SELECT  name,
        qty_ordered,
        item_id,
        original_price,
        discount_percent,
        price,
        tax_percent,
        MAX(CASE WHEN mea.attribute_code = 'cip' THEN mcpev.value END) AS cip,
        MAX(CASE WHEN mea.attribute_code = 'cip7' THEN mcpev.value END) AS cip7,
        MAX(CASE WHEN mea.attribute_code = 'gtin_13' THEN mcpev.value END) AS gtin13
FROM    magento_sales_flat_order_item msfoi
INNER JOIN magento_catalog_product_entity_varchar mcpev
  ON msfoi.product_id = mcpev.entity_id
INNER JOIN magento_eav_attribute mea
  ON mcpev.attribute_id = mea.attribute_id
WHERE   order_id = 1
GROUP BY name, qty_ordered, item_id, original_price, discount_percent, price, tax_percent
```

Comment: I think that it's working now, I just added a `MAX` before the CASE for the three ones. Can you please edit your answer to be able to accept it ?

Comment: @Lennart : Thank you very much for your hint.

Comment: This may be just sweeping the schema flaw under the rug.